# Text updation from a function in a Label in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am having a question with with four options and a timer.Now I had read a json file content and get it in questions list. After setting the GUI and shuffling the questions in question list , Now I want to update the questionText and options in Buttons. I called loadQuestion() function after all this, But my program stops abruptly after that.

```
from Tkinter import *
import json
from random import shuffle
import tkMessageBox
class ProgramGUI(Frame):
def __init__(self, master=None):
    master.title('QuizBox')
    master.update()
    master.minsize(350, 150)
    Frame.__init__(self, master)
    try:
        with open('questions.txt') as data_file:
            try:
                questions=json.load(data_file)
            except ValueError,e:
                tkMessageBox.showerror("Invalid JSON","Invlid JSON Format")
                master.destroy()
                questions=[]
            data_file.close()
    except (OSError, IOError) as err:
        tkMessageBox.showerror("File Not Found","File Not Found!!")
        master.destroy()
    questionText = StringVar()

    Label(master,textvariable=questionText,justify=CENTER,wraplength=200).pack()
    questionText.set("Question text goes here")

    timer = IntVar()
    Label(master,textvariable=timer,justify=CENTER,fg="blue").pack()
    timer.set("10")

    buttonList = ["Answer 1", "Answer 2", "Answer 3", "Answer 4"]
    self.rowconfigure(0, pad=3)
    for i, value in enumerate(buttonList):
        self.columnconfigure(i, pad=3)
        Button(self, text=value).grid(row=0, column=i)

    self.pack()

    score = IntVar()
    Label(master,textvariable=score,justify=CENTER).pack()
    score.set("Score: 0")

    shuffle(questions)
    #print questions
    loadQuestion(self)
    master.mainloop()

def loadQuestion(self):
    print questions
    if len(questions) > 0:
        # Modify the questionText StringVar with first question in question[] and delete it from questions[]

root = Tk()
gui = ProgramGUI(master=root)
root.destroy()
```

The loadQuestion() method is responsible for displaying the next question in the GUI and starting the timer.  The method must first select a question (i.e. the dictionary containing the question and answers) from the questions list and then display the text of the question in the appropriate Label and the answers in the Buttons of the GUI in a random order. Also rather than trying to randomise the order of the answers, I need to shuffle the buttonList list to randomise the order of the buttons before assigning answers to them.

The question should be removed from the question list so that it is not selected again.We can use “pop()” list method to removes the last element in a list.

The timer IntVar is set to 11 and then “updateTimer()” is called to start the timer. Rather than trying to randomise the order of the answers, I am trying to shuffle the buttonList list to randomise the order of the buttons before assigning answers to them. Since the timer is immediately updated after being set, the first number the user sees is 10.

The updateTimer() method will first subtract one from the timer IntVar, and then check if the timer is 0.  If it is, a messagebox with a “Game Over” message and the user’s score, then destroy the main window to end the program.  Otherwise (if the timer is not 0), We need to call the “updateTimer()” method again in 1 second. I think to do we can use the “after()” method for this, and by storing the ID of the upcoming call in a variable we can cancel it as needed.

Note : questionList is json format of type :

```
[{         
    "question": "Example Question 1",                
    "wrong1": "Incorrect answer",         
    "wrong2": "Another wrong one",    
    "wrong3": "Nope, also wrong",       
    "answer": "Correct answer"     
} ]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems in your code that relate to your use of instance variables, these being variables unique to an instance of an object. Instance variables are accessible within methods of the same class, and this is what you need to do to access the question list within your `loadQuestion()` method. For example:

```
questions = json.load(data_file)
```

defines a *local* variable named `questions` in the `__init__()` method, however, this variable does not exist once the `__init__()` function terminates. You need to make it an instance variable with `self` like this:

```
self.questions = json.load(data_file)
```

Now this variable can be accessed with `self.questions` in methods of the same class such as `loadQuestions()`, which would be written like this (note use of `self.`):

```
def loadQuestion(self):
    print self.questions
    if len(self.questions) > 0:
        # Modify the questionText StringVar with first question in question[] and delete it from questions[]
        pass
```

Now, to update the value of the question label requires similar changes. Declare `questionText` as an instance variable in `__init__()`:

```
self.questionText = StringVar()
```

and update it within `loadQuestions()`:

```
def loadQuestion(self):
    print self.questions
    if len(self.questions) > 0:
        # just take the first question and answers from the pre-shuffled list
        q_and_a = self.questions.pop()
        self.questionText.set(q_and_a['question'])
        # update answer buttons too....
```

You will find that you will need to use a similar method for each of the answer buttons, i.e. make these instance variables and update the button's text in `loadQuestions()`.

Comment: I tried this : http://pastebin.com/Qn2CeY1q But getting error. Am I calling function in right way ?

Comment: You need to update all `questions` to `self.questions`, for example line 44 in your revised code should read `shuffle(self.questions)`. Also lines 25 & 26 should use `self.questionText`. Any others should be easy to spot by reading and understanding the error messages.

Comment: This code is running fine but not calling loadQueston function http://pastebin.com/xi04UQ9g

Comment: `ProgramGUI.loadQuestion` is not calling a function, it's just referencing it - you need to use `()` to effect a call. Also, to call a method from another method of the same class, just use `self` as you did for the variables, i.e. `self.loadQuestion()` will work.

Comment: Why self.buttonList=[q_and_a['wrong1'],q_and_a['wrong2'],q_and_a['wrong3'],q_and_a['answer']]
             is not working ?

Comment: What updates the button's text? Changing the values in `buttonList` will not do that. You need to call `Button.config(text='new value')`. You will need to store the buttons in an instance variable, I suggest a list. Then update each button's text in `loadQuestion()` in a random fashion. You also need functions to handle button presses, and you will need to know which of the buttons is the correct answer (that could be done by binding a different function to the button with the correct answer). This is getting too complicated to answer here, try to make it work, than ask a new question.

Comment: You should also read some tutorials, perhaps take a look at http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm.

Comment: Let me make a sepearte post. I tried but no success